# model.matrix generates fewer rows than original data.frame

Tags: r, model, matrix, dataframe

Why doesn't a model matrix necessarily have the same number of rows as the data frame?

```
mergem = model.matrix(as.formula(paste(response, '~ .')), data=mergef)
dim(mergef)
# [1] 115562     71
dim(mergem)
# [1] 66786   973
```

I tried looking for hints in the documentation but couldn't find anything.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, if a row has NAs in it, that row is (by default) removed:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2), y=c(2,2,4), z=c(4,NA,8))
m <- model.matrix(x ~ ., data=d)

nrow(d) # 3
nrow(m) # 2
```

This behavior is controlled by the option "na.action":

```
options(na.action="na.fail")
m <- model.matrix(x ~ ., data=d) # Error: missing values in object
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, didn't work for me. Replaced NA's with 0 instead.

Comment: I used the na.action = "na.pass" and then in the resulting matrix subtitute the NAs for 0. This way it excludes those samples from all the contrasts dummy variables created.

Comment: also the row.names of m can be used to find the rows of m in d:

```d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2), y=c(2,2,4), z=c(4,NA,8));
m <- model.matrix(y ~ z, data=d);
dataformodelmatrix <- d[row.names(m),] ```